# Can Bluff be used to emulate an alignment?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, skills, alignment

If a character has something like the Touch of Golden Ice feat (Book of Exalted Deeds, pg41) could an evil character use bluff to avoid the ill effects, or is there an item that already does this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the epic level D&D rules, you can [use Bluff to fake your alignment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/skills.htm#bluff) - with a check DC of 70:

> **Display False Alignment**
>
> The character can fool alignment-sensing effects by displaying a false alignment of his or her choice. Once set, a false alignment remains as long as the character remains conscious and awake. Setting or changing a false alignment requires a full-round action.

However, this only affects effects that detect alignment, which could be interpreted to exclude attacks that work on alignment, like Smite Evil.

You could also craft a magic item that permanently grants the spell *[undetectable alignment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/undetectableAlignment.htm)*. The item pricing guidelines suggest a price of 2,000 gp for this. However, the spell only applies to divinations like *detect evil*.

Comment: Um.. does that also allow to fulfill alignment prerequisites?

Comment: @JeorMattan: Not for feats, prestige classes, etc, because you're only disguising your alignment, not changing it. It could fool a magic item, perhaps. You can also fake your alignment with a DC 30 Use Magic Device check.

Comment: Touch of golden ice would still affect you.